# Camera movement descriptor into lists of x,y,z points

Tags: 3dsmax, 3ds

is there a way to export a camera movements that lists N points of the trajectory ?
For the moment I can export to this:

```
*SHAPEOBJECT {
    *NODE_NAME "Line003"
    *NODE_TM {
        *NODE_NAME "Line003"
        *INHERIT_POS 0 0 0
        *INHERIT_ROT 0 0 0
        *INHERIT_SCL 0 0 0
        *TM_ROW0 1.0000 0.0000  0.0000
        *TM_ROW1 0.0000 -0.0000 1.0000
        *TM_ROW2 0.0000 -1.0000 -0.0000
        *TM_ROW3 9.8722 0.0000  -6.2583
        *TM_POS 9.8722  0.0000  -6.2583
        *TM_ROTAXIS -1.0000 -0.0000 -0.0000
        *TM_ROTANGLE 1.5708
        *TM_SCALE 1.0000    1.0000  1.0000
        *TM_SCALEAXIS 0.0000    0.0000  0.0000
        *TM_SCALEAXISANG 0.0000
    }
    *SHAPE_LINECOUNT 1
    *SHAPE_LINE 0 {
        *SHAPE_VERTEXCOUNT 2
        *SHAPE_VERTEX_KNOT  0   -1.1622 0.0000  -12.1719
        *SHAPE_VERTEX_KNOT  1   25.1017 0.0042  0.5356
    }
}
```

Buy I need something like

```
25.1017 0.0132  0.5356
24.1017 0.0232  0.5356
22.1017 0.0342  0.5356
21.1017 0.0472  0.5356
20.1017 0.0562  0.5356
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem like this script may help :

http://algorithmist.wordpress.com/2007/09/18/spline-to-xml-maxscript/